# Load videos (not from youtube) into chromeless player (can it be done ??)

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

From what I understand the chromeless player..
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html

can be loaded as an external swf and can play youtube videos
using commands like:cueVideoById, or cueVideoByUrl

Both commands apply to youtube videos, but is there a way to have the player load a video let's say hosted on your server ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible using the YouTube chromeless player. I'm sure that there are other Flash options out there if you search around a bit, though. You could also use the HTML5  tag, assuming your users are running a compatible browser.